# Add objects to core data only once

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, core-data

I want to create a large database. I am thinking of using core data for this purpose.But i want to insert the data to it manually and only once. This data is never deleted or edited but only read. How can i use core data to add such large number of objects to database? How to create database in core data and write only once.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite general but I'll try to give you some hints on it.

Based on my experience, the simplest way to achieve it, it's to follow these two steps:

1) You could create an external file, in XML, JSON or plist format, that you can parse and use to create a prepulated a Core Data store. You can find some info in [core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data-updated](http://www.raywenderlich.com/12170/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data-updated). In particular, you could set up a dummy project (or just use the `AppDelegate` methods) and use it to create the store, e.g. MyDataStore.sqlite.

2) Once you created, forget about the routines you have previously used and you ship the store in the application's bundle of your app. There the store is read-only. Otherwise, if you need to modify it, you are not allowed to do it and so you need to move it, for example, to the document directory.

You cand find additional info in the following SO topics:

[Is Core Data useful for readonly data too?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638443/is-core-data-useful-for-readonly-data-too)

[How can I ship my app with a pre-populated Core Data database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029653/how-can-i-ship-my-app-with-an-pre-populated-core-data-database)

[Core Data Store included in App Bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633079/core-data-store-included-in-app-bundle)

P.S. If you are in production and you need to make same change to your store, you need to republish the app (since the store is within the main bundle). To avoid this you need to move the store to a different directory and set up, for example, a sort of sync mechanism.

Hope that helps.